# How to prevent CSRF attack in ASP.Net Web Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, session-cookies, csrf

I want to prevent My Web Application from the CSRF attacks.

I'm applying this solution for the same in Master Page, all the Web Pages are inherited from this Master Page.

```
public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
{
    private const string AntiXsrfTokenKey = "__AntiXsrfToken";
    private const string AntiXsrfUserNameKey = "__AntiXsrfUserName";
    private string _antiXsrfTokenValue;

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //First, check for the existence of the Anti-XSS cookie
        var requestCookie = Request.Cookies[AntiXsrfTokenKey];
        Guid requestCookieGuidValue;

        //If the CSRF cookie is found, parse the token from the cookie.
        //Then, set the global page variable and view state user
        //key. The global variable will be used to validate that it matches in the view state form field in the Page.PreLoad
        //method.
        if (requestCookie != null
        && Guid.TryParse(requestCookie.Value, out requestCookieGuidValue))
        {
            //Set the global token variable so the cookie value can be
            //validated against the value in the view state form field in
            //the Page.PreLoad method.
            _antiXsrfTokenValue = requestCookie.Value;

            //Set the view state user key, which will be validated by the
            //framework during each request
            Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;
        }
        //If the CSRF cookie is not found, then this is a new session.
        else
        {
            //Generate a new Anti-XSRF token
            _antiXsrfTokenValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

            //Set the view state user key, which will be validated by the
            //framework during each request
            Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;

            //Create the non-persistent CSRF cookie
            var responseCookie = new HttpCookie(AntiXsrfTokenKey)
            {
                //Set the HttpOnly property to prevent the cookie from
                //being accessed by client side script
                HttpOnly = true,

                //Add the Anti-XSRF token to the cookie value
                Value = _antiXsrfTokenValue
            };

            //If we are using SSL, the cookie should be set to secure to
            //prevent it from being sent over HTTP connections
            if (FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL &&
            Request.IsSecureConnection)
            responseCookie.Secure = true;

            //Add the CSRF cookie to the response
            Response.Cookies.Set(responseCookie);
        }

            Page.PreLoad += master_Page_PreLoad;
        }

        protected void master_Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //During the initial page load, add the Anti-XSRF token and user
            //name to the ViewState
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //Set Anti-XSRF token
                ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] = Page.ViewStateUserKey;

                //If a user name is assigned, set the user name
                ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] =
                Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty;
            }
            //During all subsequent post backs to the page, the token value from
            //the cookie should be validated against the token in the view state
            //form field. Additionally user name should be compared to the
            //authenticated users name
            else
            {
                //Validate the Anti-XSRF token
                if ((string)ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] != _antiXsrfTokenValue
                || (string)ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] !=
                (Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty))
            {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Validation of
            Anti-XSRF token failed.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this Solution I'm not able to achieve what I want.

If User A logs in, does some activity and capture the Request from Fiddler and it logs out and now User B logs in and I fire the captured Request and it successfully does it task. So My application is not prevented.

I can see Request.Cookies[AntiXsrfTokenKey] value is same for a particular session and for a new session Request.Cookies[AntiXsrfTokenKey] value is different.

What should I do insted of this line

```
throw new InvalidOperationException("Validation of Anti-XSRF token failed.");
```

On LogOut Button Click I clear each and everything.

```
 FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

        Session.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();
        Session.RemoveAll();

        HttpCookie cookies = Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];//Or Response
        cookies.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        Context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookies);

        if (Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"] != null)
        {
            Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value = string.Empty;
            Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-20);
        }

        if (Request.Cookies["AuthToken"] != null)
        {
            Response.Cookies["AuthToken"].Value = string.Empty;
            Response.Cookies["AuthToken"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-20);
        }

        if (Request.Cookies[AntiXsrfTokenKey] != null)
        {
            Response.Cookies[AntiXsrfTokenKey].Value = string.Empty;
            Response.Cookies[AntiXsrfTokenKey].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-20);
        }


        //Response.Redirect("Logon.aspx");
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in the form that send the data. Then decorate the action method or controller with the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateantiforgerytokenattribute.aspx)

Comment: its not based on MVC , its asp.net 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Use "AntiForgeryToken" to prevent CSRF attack. For better understanding refer the below links:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-(csrf)-attacks

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/686881/Hack-Proof-Your-ASP-NET-Applica

Comment: its not based on MVC , its asp.net 4.0